# How to bind DocumentDB input to Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that I created in the Azure portal and now want to recreate it using the visual studio azure tooling associated with VS2017 Preview.

My function is Timer triggered, and also has an input binding for Azure DocumentDB (with a query) and an output binding to an Azure Service Bus queue.

Here's the `functions.json` definition from the portal:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "name": "outputQueue",
      "queueName": "test-output-requests",
      "connection": "send-refresh-request",
      "accessRights_": "Send",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "incomingDocuments",
      "databaseName": "test-db-dev",
      "collectionName": "TestingCollection",
      "sqlQuery": "select * from c where c.docType = \"Test\"",
      "connection": "my-testing_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

In VS2017, I create an Azure Function project, then a Azure function using the TimerTriggered template:

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, ICollector<dynamic> outputQueue, IEnumerable<dynamic> incomingDocuments)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");   

    //Inspect incomingDocuments .. push messages to outputQueue
}
```

Running locally, the timer is triggered as expected - but how do I recreate the input and output bindings in code? I'm not sure what attributes I should use, and what I need in json config files to wire it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add reference to following nuget pacakge
   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB/
2. Add `using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs`
3. Update the documentDb Parameter as follows (Add other properties as well)

   ```
   [DocumentDB(ConnectionStringSetting = "")]IEnumerable<dynamic> incomingDocuments
   ```
4. Update the serviceBus Parameter as follows

   ```
   [ServiceBus("test-output-requests",Connection = "ConnectionValue")]
   ```

Verify the generated function.json in the `bin/functionName/function.json`

Thanks, 
Naren

Comment: Thanks that has pointed me in the right direction. Two extras of note:

I needed to reference v1.1.0-beta1 of [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB/) pkg.
 
The binding for `ServiceBus` attribute has a serialization bug causing an incorrect definition in `function.json`, waiting on an update to that NuGet pkg, see GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/40)

Comment: Further pkg update is now [available](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/1.0.0-alpha4) with a fix for the ServiceBus issue.